# return a specific bit as boolean from a byte value

Tags: c#, math, byte, converters

I have a function that convert a Byte to an 8 bit address and returns the bit on the location that is specified in the parameter.

The way it's build now it works fine, but it's pretty ugly in my opinion is there a way to do this with a method in math or something in that direction, I tried looking for another approach but didn't came up with anything.

```
    private bool ConvertByteToBitAddres(byte byteToConvert, int bitToReturn)
    {
        bool[] address = new bool[8];
        int remaining = byteToConvert;


        if (remaining > 128)
        {
            remaining = remaining - remaining;
            address[7] = true;
        }
        if (remaining > 64 || remaining < 128)
        {
            remaining = remaining - remaining;
            address[6] = true;
        }
        if (remaining > 32)
        {
            remaining = remaining - remaining;
            address[5] = true;
        }
        if (remaining > 16)
        {
            remaining = remaining - remaining;
            address[4] = true;
        }
        if (remaining > 8)
        {
            remaining = remaining - remaining;
            address[3] = true;
        }
        if (remaining > 4)
        {
            remaining = remaining - remaining;
            address[2] = true;
        }
        if (remaining > 2)
        {
            remaining = remaining - remaining;
            address[1] = true;
        }
        if (remaining > 1)
        {
            remaining = remaining - remaining;
            address[0] = true;
        }

        if (remaining == 0)
        {
            return address[bitToReturn];
        }
        throw new Exception();
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use bitwise operations; for example:

```
int mask = 1 << (bitToReturn - 1); // if "bitToReturn" is 1-based
// int mask = 1 << bitToReturn; // if "bitToReturn" is 0-based
return (byteToConvert & mask) != 0
```

Perhaps easier, though, is to just pass in the `mask` rather than `bitToReturn`.

Comment: @Robin I should also have noted: the CPU is **very very good** at bitwise operations, so if doing this type of thing they should always be preferred. For example, `|` instead of `+` is preferable for *forming* composite bitwise values.

Comment: I see, I'm not yet familiar enough with bitwise operations to use it in the field so I guess I'll be doing some reading-up in the near future.

Answer (score 4):

Use a bitmask.

```
private bool ConvertByteToBitAddres(byte byteToConvert, int bitToReturn)
{
    int mask = 1 << bitToReturn;
    return (byteToConvert & mask) == mask;
}
```

Comment: Since we know this is a single-bit test, it is **marginally** easier to test against 0 rather than equality to the mask.

Answer (score 0):

Another option that might be suitable is to use BitVector32:

```
byte b = 10;
var bv = new BitVector32(b);

for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Value of bit {i}:  {bv[1 << i]}");
}

//You could also declare consts for each bit and use that:
const int Bit0 = 1;
const int Bit1 = 2;
const int Bit2 = 4;
const int Bit3 = 8;

Console.WriteLine($"\r\nValue of bit 3:  {bv[Bit3]}");
```

Output:

```
Value of bit 0:  False
Value of bit 1:  True 
Value of bit 2:  False
Value of bit 3:  True 
Value of bit 4:  False 
Value of bit 5:  False
Value of bit 6:  False 
Value of bit 7:  False

Value of bit 3:  True
```

Comment: This is actually not how the index works. It treats the specified value as a mask, not as a bit position.

Comment: @Rev1.0 - Thanks.  I misread the docs for the indexer.  I don't like how MS implemented it though.  The `CreateMask` method is odd, in my opinion.  I updated my code.  For a bit flag, I find using, for example, 1 << 2 to get the bit at index 2 more readable.

Comment: 100% agree that the implementation is kind of weird. Accessing a single bit at a specific position should be as easy as possible. I misused it the same way as you did the first time.